# Move billing address form to shipping address page in magento 2.1

Tags: magento-2.1, checkout, billing-address

I am using Magento-2.1.7. I am trying to move where the billing address is set by default it is set on the payment page and I would like to move this to the shipping methods section.

Here is my **checkout_index_index.xml**:

```
<item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
<item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">before-shipping-method-form</item>
<item name="children" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="billing-address" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/payment/default</item>
        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/billing-address</item>
        <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">billing-address</item>
        <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">afterMethods</item>
        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">checkoutProvider</item>
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/billing-address</item>
        </item>
    </item>
</item>
```

This is loading the checkbox and label but the form is empty

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uH5B7.png]

Comment: hi , any update on this??

Comment: No sorry no luck @gajjalasandeep

Comment: Bounty +50 is not enough for this :D @gajjalasandeep . I will help you when have time.

Answer (score 17):

Try to follow all step:

Step 1: **SR/ModifiedCheckout/etc/module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="SR_ModifiedCheckout" setup_version="2.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Checkout"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

Step 2: SR/ModifiedCheckout/registration.php

```
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'SR_ModifiedCheckout',
    __DIR__
);
```

Step 3: SR/ModifiedCheckout/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor">
        <plugin name="sr_modified_checkout_layout_processor" type="SR\ModifiedCheckout\Plugin\Block\LayoutProcessor" sortOrder="1"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

Step 4: SR/ModifiedCheckout/Plugin/Block/LayoutProcessor.php

```
namespace SR\ModifiedCheckout\Plugin\Block;

use Magento\Customer\Model\AttributeMetadataDataProvider;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\AttributeMapper;
use Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\AttributeMerger;
use Magento\Checkout\Model\Session as CheckoutSession;

class LayoutProcessor
{
    /**
     * @var AttributeMetadataDataProvider
     */
    public $attributeMetadataDataProvider;

    /**
     * @var AttributeMapper
     */
    public $attributeMapper;

    /**
     * @var AttributeMerger
     */
    public $merger;

    /**
     * @var CheckoutSession
     */
    public $checkoutSession;

    /**
     * @var null
     */
    public $quote = null;

    /**
     * LayoutProcessor constructor.
     *
     * @param AttributeMetadataDataProvider $attributeMetadataDataProvider
     * @param AttributeMapper $attributeMapper
     * @param AttributeMerger $merger
     * @param CheckoutSession $checkoutSession
     */
    public function __construct(
        AttributeMetadataDataProvider $attributeMetadataDataProvider,
        AttributeMapper $attributeMapper,
        AttributeMerger $merger,
        CheckoutSession $checkoutSession
    ) {
        $this->attributeMetadataDataProvider = $attributeMetadataDataProvider;
        $this->attributeMapper = $attributeMapper;
        $this->merger = $merger;
        $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
    }

    /**
     * Get Quote
     *
     * @return \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote|null
     */
    public function getQuote()
    {
        if (null === $this->quote) {
            $this->quote = $this->checkoutSession->getQuote();
        }

        return $this->quote;
    }

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject
     * @param array $jsLayout
     * @return array
     */
    public function aroundProcess(
        \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject,
        \Closure $proceed,
        array $jsLayout
    ) {

        $jsLayoutResult = $proceed($jsLayout);

        if($this->getQuote()->isVirtual()) {
            return $jsLayoutResult;
        }

        if(isset($jsLayoutResult['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']
            ['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset'])) {

            $jsLayoutResult['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']
            ['children']['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']['street']['children'][0]['placeholder'] = __('Street Address');
            $jsLayoutResult['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']
            ['children']['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']['street']['children'][1]['placeholder'] = __('Street line 2');

            $elements = $this->getAddressAttributes();
            $jsLayoutResult['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']
            ['children']['shippingAddress']['children']['billing-address'] = $this->getCustomBillingAddressComponent($elements);

            $jsLayoutResult['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']
            ['children']['shippingAddress']['children']['billing-address']['children']['form-fields']['children']['street']['children'][0]['placeholder'] = __('Street Address');
            $jsLayoutResult['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']
            ['children']['shippingAddress']['children']['billing-address']['children']['form-fields']['children']['street']['children'][1]['placeholder'] = __('Street line 2');
        }

        return $jsLayoutResult;
    }

    /**
     * Get all visible address attribute
     *
     * @return array
     */
    private function getAddressAttributes()
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Eav\Api\Data\AttributeInterface[] $attributes */
        $attributes = $this->attributeMetadataDataProvider->loadAttributesCollection(
            'customer_address',
            'customer_register_address'
        );

        $elements = [];
        foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
            $code = $attribute->getAttributeCode();
            if ($attribute->getIsUserDefined()) {
                continue;
            }
            $elements[$code] = $this->attributeMapper->map($attribute);
            if (isset($elements[$code]['label'])) {
                $label = $elements[$code]['label'];
                $elements[$code]['label'] = __($label);
            }
        }
        return $elements;
    }

    /**
     * Prepare billing address field for shipping step for physical product
     *
     * @param $elements
     * @return array
     */
    public function getCustomBillingAddressComponent($elements)
    {
        return [
            'component' => 'SR_ModifiedCheckout/js/view/billing-address',
            'displayArea' => 'billing-address',
            'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
            'deps' => ['checkoutProvider'],
            'dataScopePrefix' => 'billingAddress',
            'children' => [
                'form-fields' => [
                    'component' => 'uiComponent',
                    'displayArea' => 'additional-fieldsets',
                    'children' => $this->merger->merge(
                        $elements,
                        'checkoutProvider',
                        'billingAddress',
                        [
                            'country_id' => [
                                'sortOrder' => 115,
                            ],
                            'region' => [
                                'visible' => false,
                            ],
                            'region_id' => [
                                'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/region',
                                'config' => [
                                    'template' => 'ui/form/field',
                                    'elementTmpl' => 'ui/form/element/select',
                                    'customEntry' => 'billingAddress.region',
                                ],
                                'validation' => [
                                    'required-entry' => true,
                                ],
                                'filterBy' => [
                                    'target' => '${ $.provider }:${ $.parentScope }.country_id',
                                    'field' => 'country_id',
                                ],
                            ],
                            'postcode' => [
                                'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/post-code',
                                'validation' => [
                                    'required-entry' => true,
                                ],
                            ],
                            'company' => [
                                'validation' => [
                                    'min_text_length' => 0,
                                ],
                            ],
                            'fax' => [
                                'validation' => [
                                    'min_text_length' => 0,
                                ],
                            ],
                            'telephone' => [
                                'config' => [
                                    'tooltip' => [
                                        'description' => __('For delivery questions.'),
                                    ],
                                ],
                            ],
                        ]
                    ),
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }
}
```

Step 5: SR/ModifiedCheckout/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="shipping-step" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="shippingAddress" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">SR_ModifiedCheckout/address</item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                                <item name="overwriteShippingComponent" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">SR_ModifiedCheckout/js/view/shipping</item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
   </body>
</page>
```

Step 6:SR/ModifiedCheckout/view/frontend/web/js/view/billing-address.js

```
/*jshint browser:true*/
/*global define*/
define(
    [
        'ko',
        'underscore',
        'jquery',
        'Magento_Ui/js/form/form',
        'Magento_Customer/js/model/customer',
        'Magento_Customer/js/model/address-list',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/action/create-billing-address',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/action/select-billing-address',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/checkout-data',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/checkout-data-resolver',
        'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/action/set-billing-address',
        'Magento_Ui/js/model/messageList',
        'mage/translate'
    ],
    function (
        ko,
        _,
        $,
        Component,
        customer,
        addressList,
        quote,
        createBillingAddress,
        selectBillingAddress,
        checkoutData,
        checkoutDataResolver,
        customerData,
        setBillingAddressAction,
        globalMessageList,
        $t

    ) {
        'use strict';

        var newAddressOption = {
                /**
                 * Get new address label
                 * @returns {String}
                 */
                getAddressInline: function () {
                    return $t('New Address');
                },
                customerAddressId: null
            },
            countryData = customerData.get('directory-data'),
            addressOptions = addressList().filter(function (address) {
                return address.getType() == 'customer-address';
            });

        addressOptions.push(newAddressOption);

        return Component.extend({
            defaults: {
                template: 'SR_ModifiedCheckout/billing-address'
            },
            currentBillingAddress: quote.billingAddress,
            addressOptions: addressOptions,
            customerHasAddresses: addressOptions.length > 1,

            /**
             * Init component
             */
            initialize: function () {
                this._super();
            },

            /**
             * @return {exports.initObservable}
             */
            initObservable: function () {
                this._super()
                    .observe({
                        selectedAddress: null,
                        isAddressFormVisible: false,
                        isAddressSameAsShipping: true,
                        saveInAddressBook: 1,
                        isAddressFormListVisible:false
                    });

                return this;
            },

            canUseShippingAddress: ko.computed(function () {
                return !quote.isVirtual() && quote.shippingAddress() && quote.shippingAddress().canUseForBilling();
            }),

            /**
             * @param {Object} address
             * @return {*}
             */
            addressOptionsText: function (address) {
                return address.getAddressInline();
            },

            /**
             * @return {Boolean}
             */
            useShippingAddress: function () {
                if (this.isAddressSameAsShipping()) {
                    this.isAddressFormVisible(false);
                    this.isAddressFormListVisible(false);
                } else {
                    if(addressOptions.length == 1) {
                        this.isAddressFormVisible(true);
                    } else {
                        this.isAddressFormListVisible(true);
                    }
                }
                return true;
            },
            /**
             * @param {Object} address
             */
            onAddressChange: function (address) {
                if(address) {
                    this.isAddressFormVisible(false);
                } else {
                    this.isAddressFormVisible(true);
                }
            },

            /**
             * @param {int} countryId
             * @return {*}
             */
            getCountryName: function (countryId) {
                return countryData()[countryId] != undefined ? countryData()[countryId].name : '';
            },

            /**
             * Get code
             * @param {Object} parent
             * @returns {String}
             */
            getCode: function (parent) {
                return _.isFunction(parent.getCode) ? parent.getCode() : 'shared';
            }
        });
    }
);
```

Step 7:SR/ModifiedCheckout/view/frontend/web/js/view/shipping.js

```
define(
    [
        'jquery',
        'underscore',
        'Magento_Ui/js/form/form',
        'ko',
        'Magento_Customer/js/model/customer',
        'Magento_Customer/js/model/address-list',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/address-converter',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/action/create-shipping-address',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/action/select-shipping-address',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/view/shipping',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/action/create-billing-address',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/action/select-billing-address',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/action/set-shipping-information',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/step-navigator',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/checkout-data'
    ],
    function(
        $,
        _,
        Component,
        ko,
        customer,
        addressList,
        addressConverter,
        quote,
        createShippingAddress,
        selectShippingAddress,
        shipping,
        createBillingAddress,
        selectBillingAddress,
        setShippingInformationAction,
        stepNavigator,
        checkoutData
    ) {
        'use strict';

        _.extend(shipping.prototype, {
            setShippingInformation: function () {
                if (this.validateShippingInformation() && this.validateBillingInformation()) {
                    setShippingInformationAction().done(
                        function () {
                            stepNavigator.next();
                        }
                    );
                }
            },
            validateBillingInformation: function() {

                if($('[name="billing-address-same-as-shipping"]').is(":checked")) {
                    if (this.isFormInline) {
                        var shippingAddress = quote.shippingAddress();
                        var addressData = addressConverter.formAddressDataToQuoteAddress(
                            this.source.get('shippingAddress')
                        );
                        //Copy form data to quote shipping address object
                        for (var field in addressData) {

                            if (addressData.hasOwnProperty(field) &&
                                shippingAddress.hasOwnProperty(field) &&
                                typeof addressData[field] != 'function' &&
                                _.isEqual(shippingAddress[field], addressData[field])
                            ) {
                                shippingAddress[field] = addressData[field];
                            } else if (typeof addressData[field] != 'function' &&
                                !_.isEqual(shippingAddress[field], addressData[field])) {
                                shippingAddress = addressData;
                                break;
                            }
                        }

                        if (customer.isLoggedIn()) {
                            shippingAddress.save_in_address_book = 1;
                        }
                        var newBillingAddress = createBillingAddress(shippingAddress);
                        selectBillingAddress(newBillingAddress);
                    } else {
                        selectBillingAddress(quote.shippingAddress());
                    }

                    return true;
                }

                var selectedAddress = $('[name="billing_address_id"]').val();
                if(selectedAddress) {
                    var res = addressList.some(function (addressFromList) {
                        if (selectedAddress == addressFromList.customerAddressId) {
                            selectBillingAddress(addressFromList);
                            return true;
                        }
                        return false;
                    });

                    return res;
                }

                this.source.set('params.invalid', false);
                this.source.trigger('billingAddress.data.validate');

                if (this.source.get('params.invalid')) {
                    return false;
                }

                var addressData = this.source.get('billingAddress'),
                    newBillingAddress;

                if ($('#billing-save-in-address-book').is(":checked")) {
                    addressData.save_in_address_book = 1;
                }

                newBillingAddress = createBillingAddress(addressData);
                selectBillingAddress(newBillingAddress);

                return true;
            }
        });

        return Component.extend({});
    }
);
```

[Download full module from here](https://github.com/sohelrana09/modified-checkout)

Comment: Hey Buddy,

It works fine but how to keep the data persist after filling the billing address form like we are having it in the shipping section. I would like to keep the data prefilled if we refresh the checkout page.

Comment: after use, your module Name Prefix convert into the textbox. That should be shown in a drop-down. Please advise!

Comment: Hi @Sohel, this solution was working fine until 2.2.4, after upgrading magento to 2.2.5 version it started showing following error. "Please check the billing address information. regionId is a required field."

Comment: I will check and update this as well, thanks for letting me know.

Comment: Its working fine but it not storing db so it's not reflecting in myorders Sohel Rana

Comment: Hi @SohelRana i tried your modul https://github.com/sohelrana09/modified-checkout but this wont work. in your repo there is no definition of checkout_index_index.xml. My Version is Magento 2.2.6 .. do you have a version for this?

Answer (score 7):

**Continue**

Step 8:SR/ModifiedCheckout/view/frontend/web/template/billing-address.html

```
<div class="checkout-billing-address">

    <div class="billing-address-same-as-shipping-block field choice" data-bind="visible: canUseShippingAddress()">
        <input type="checkbox" name="billing-address-same-as-shipping"
               data-bind="checked: isAddressSameAsShipping, click: useShippingAddress, attr: {id: 'billing-address-same-as-shipping'}"/>
        <label data-bind="attr: {for: 'billing-address-same-as-shipping'}">
            <span data-bind="i18n: 'This address is also my billing address'"></span>
        </label>
    </div>
    <fieldset class="fieldset">
        <!-- ko template: 'SR_ModifiedCheckout/billing-address/list' --><!-- /ko -->
        <!-- ko template: 'SR_ModifiedCheckout/billing-address/form' --><!-- /ko -->
    </fieldset>

</div>
```

Step 9: SR/ModifiedCheckout/view/frontend/web/template/address.html

```
<li id="shipping" class="checkout-shipping-address" data-bind="fadeVisible: visible()">
    <div class="step-title" data-bind="i18n: 'Shipping Address'" data-role="title"></div>
    <div id="checkout-step-shipping"
         class="step-content"
         data-role="content">

        <!-- ko if: (!quoteIsVirtual) -->
            <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('customer-email') -->
                <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
            <!--/ko-->
        <!--/ko-->

        <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('address-list') -->
        <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
        <!--/ko-->

        <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('address-list-additional-addresses') -->
        <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
        <!--/ko-->

        <!-- Address form pop up -->
        <!-- ko if: (!isFormInline) -->
        <button type="button"
                data-bind="click: showFormPopUp, visible: !isNewAddressAdded()"
                class="action action-show-popup">
            <span data-bind="i18n: 'New Address'"></span></button>
        <div id="opc-new-shipping-address" data-bind="visible: isFormPopUpVisible()">
            <!-- ko template: 'Magento_Checkout/shipping-address/form' --><!-- /ko -->
        </div>
        <!-- /ko -->

        <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('before-form') -->
        <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
        <!--/ko-->

        <!-- Inline address form -->
        <!-- ko if: (isFormInline) -->
        <!-- ko template: 'Magento_Checkout/shipping-address/form' --><!-- /ko -->
        <!-- /ko -->

        <!-- ko if: (isFormInline) -->
        <span class="mandatory" data-bind="i18n: 'Mandatory fields'"></span>
        <!-- /ko -->
        <!-- Inline Billing address form -->
        <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('billing-address') -->
        <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
        <!-- /ko -->
    </div>
</li>


<!--Shipping method template-->
<li id="opc-shipping_method"
    class="checkout-shipping-method"
    data-bind="fadeVisible: visible(), blockLoader: isLoading"
    role="presentation">
    <div class="checkout-shipping-method">
        <div class="step-title" data-bind="i18n: 'Shipping Methods'" data-role="title"></div>
        <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('before-shipping-method-form') -->
        <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
        <!-- /ko -->
        <div id="checkout-step-shipping_method"
             class="step-content"
             data-role="content"
             role="tabpanel"
             aria-hidden="false">
            <!-- ko if: rates().length  -->
            <form class="form methods-shipping" id="co-shipping-method-form" data-bind="submit: setShippingInformation" novalidate="novalidate">
                <div id="checkout-shipping-method-load">
                    <table class="table-checkout-shipping-method">
                        <thead>
                            <tr class="row">
                                <th class="col col-method" data-bind="i18n: 'Select Method'"></th>
                                <th class="col col-price" data-bind="i18n: 'Price'"></th>
                                <th class="col col-method" data-bind="i18n: 'Method Title'"></th>
                                <th class="col col-carrier" data-bind="i18n: 'Carrier Title'"></th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>

                        <!--ko foreach: { data: rates(), as: 'method'}-->
                        <tr class="row" data-bind="click: $parent.selectShippingMethod">
                            <td class="col col-method">
                                <!-- ko ifnot: method.error_message -->
                                <!-- ko if: $parent.rates().length == 1 -->
                                <input class="radio"
                                       type="radio"
                                       data-bind="attr: {
                                                    checked: $parent.rates().length == 1,
                                                    'value' : method.carrier_code + '_' + method.method_code,
                                                    'id': 's_method_' + method.method_code,
                                                    'aria-labelledby': 'label_method_' + method.method_code + '_' + method.carrier_code + ' ' + 'label_carrier_' + method.method_code + '_' + method.carrier_code
                                                 }" />
                                <!-- /ko -->
                                <!--ko ifnot: ($parent.rates().length == 1)-->
                                <input type="radio"
                                       data-bind="
                                                value: method.carrier_code + '_' + method.method_code,
                                                checked: $parent.isSelected,
                                                attr: {
                                                    'id': 's_method_' + method.carrier_code + '_' + method.method_code,
                                                    'aria-labelledby': 'label_method_' + method.method_code + '_' + method.carrier_code + ' ' + 'label_carrier_' + method.method_code + '_' + method.carrier_code
                                                },
                                                click: $parent.selectShippingMethod"
                                       class="radio"/>
                                <!--/ko-->
                                <!-- /ko -->
                            </td>
                            <td class="col col-price">
                                <!-- ko foreach: $parent.getRegion('price') -->
                                <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
                                <!-- /ko -->
                            </td>

                            <td class="col col-method"
                                    data-bind="text: method.method_title, attr: {'id': 'label_method_' + method.method_code + '_' + method.carrier_code}"></td>

                            <td class="col col-carrier"
                                    data-bind="text: method.carrier_title, attr: {'id': 'label_carrier_' + method.method_code + '_' + method.carrier_code}"></td>
                        </tr>

                        <!-- ko if:  method.error_message -->
                        <tr class="row row-error">
                            <td class="col col-error" colspan="4">
                                <div class="message error">
                                    <div data-bind="text: method.error_message"></div>
                                </div>
                                <span class="no-display">
                                    <input type="radio" data-bind="attr: {'value' : method.method_code, 'id': 's_method_' + method.method_code}"/>
                                </span>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <!-- /ko -->

                        <!-- /ko -->
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>

                <div id="onepage-checkout-shipping-method-additional-load">
                    <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('shippingAdditional') -->
                    <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
                    <!-- /ko -->
                </div>
                <!-- ko if: errorValidationMessage().length > 0 -->
                <div class="message notice">
                    <span><!-- ko text: errorValidationMessage()--><!-- /ko --></span>
                </div>
                <!-- /ko -->
                <div class="actions-toolbar" id="shipping-method-buttons-container">
                    <div class="primary">
                        <button data-role="opc-continue" type="submit" class="button action continue primary">
                            <span><!-- ko i18n: 'Next'--><!-- /ko --></span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
            <!-- /ko -->
            <!-- ko ifnot: rates().length > 0 --><div class="no-quotes-block"><!-- ko i18n: 'Sorry, no quotes are available for this order at this time'--><!-- /ko --></div><!-- /ko -->
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

Step 10:SR/ModifiedCheckout/view/frontend/web/template/billing-address/form.html

```
<div class="billing-address-form" data-bind="fadeVisible: isAddressFormVisible">
    <div class="step-title" data-bind="i18n: 'Billing Address'" data-role="title">
    <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('before-fields') -->
    <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
    <!--/ko-->
    <fieldset id="billing-new-address-form" class="fieldset address">
        <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('additional-fieldsets') -->
        <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
        <!--/ko-->
        <!-- ko if: (isCustomerLoggedIn) -->
        <div class="field save-address">
            <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="billing-save-in-address-book" data-bind="checked: saveInAddressBook" />
            <label class="label" for="billing-save-in-address-book">
                <span data-bind="i18n: 'Save in address book'"></span>
            </label>
        </div>
        <!-- /ko -->
        <span class="mandatory" data-bind="i18n: 'Mandatory fields'">
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

Step 11:SR/ModifiedCheckout/view/frontend/web/template/billing-address/list.html

```
<!-- ko if: (customerHasAddresses && isAddressFormListVisible)-->
<div class="field field-select-billing">
    <div class="control" data-bind="if: (addressOptions.length > 1)">
        <select class="select" id="billing_address_id" name="billing_address_id" data-bind="
        options: addressOptions,
        optionsText: addressOptionsText,
        optionsValue: 'customerAddressId',
        value: selectedAddress,
        event: {change: onAddressChange(selectedAddress())};
    "></select>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Comment: Thanks for your code, works great. But i'm having an issue with autofill because it won't work anymore for billing address. It will autofill but magento doesn't see the values. For the shipping form it still works great. Any idea on this? Can it be that there isn't a form attribute around it?

Comment: Showing error in console - `Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "if: function(){return (addressOptions.length > 1) }"`

Comment: Check https://github.com/sohelrana09/modified-checkout

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you have achieved what you were looking to do. However, I tried the approach as in the question and the thing which was missing was the LayoutProcessor plugin which actually loads the billing-address-form when you uncheck the 'my billing address is not the same as shipping address' checkbox.
 My solution to this would be:

```
....
<item name="shipping-step" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="shippingAddress" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="shipping-address-fieldset" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="billing-address" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                                                <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">billing-address</item>
                                                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <!-- merge additional data after shipping address here -->
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
```

And then \etc\di.xml create a plugin reference

```
<type name="Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor">
    <plugin name="<module>_move_billing_address_component_core" type="<module>\Plugin\Block\LayoutProcessor" />
</type>
```

Also, your plugin can look like this(you will have to add the missing constructor and the function calls from the core LayoutProcessor):

```
 /**
 * Process js Layout of block
 *
 * @param array $jsLayout
 * @return array
 * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
 */
public function afterProcess(BaseLayoutProcessor $subject, $jsLayout)
{
    //this reference is deprecated, but I am using the same
    $attributesToConvert = [
        'prefix' => [$this->getOptions(), 'getNamePrefixOptions'],
        'suffix' => [$this->getOptions(), 'getNameSuffixOptions'],
    ];

    $elements = $this->getAddressAttributes();
    $elements = $this->convertElementsToSelect($elements, $attributesToConvert);
    //unset the existing billing-address component
    unset($jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']
        ['payment']['children']['afterMethods']);

    if (isset($jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']
        ['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children'])) {
        //reference to the component where you want the billing address added
        $billingAddressLayout = &$jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']
        ['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children'];

        if (!isset($billingAddressLayout['billing-address']['children'])) {
            $billingAddressLayout['billing-address']['children'] = [];
        }
        $component['billing-address-form']                   = $this->getBillingAddressComponent('shared', $elements);
        $billingAddressLayout['billing-address']['children'] =
            array_merge_recursive(
                $component,
                $billingAddressLayout['billing-address']['children']
            );

    }

    return $jsLayout;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this below extension given here in my blog:

https://marketplace.magento.com/ananta-module-improvedcheckout.html

Tested and worked with 2.4.5

[image]
[image]