# Magento 2 : Remove Billing Address From Payment Step in Checkout

Tags: checkout, magento2.2, knockoutjs, shipping-address, billing-address

In the payment step under checkout in Magento 2, I'm trying to remove the address and the option: 'My billing and shipping address are the same
'. Because I have added billing address to shipping step.

I got a `LayoutProcessor.php` and I'm trying to edit the `$jsLayout` but I'm unsure if this is the way to go and what path to unset it at.

I currently got the following code which doesn't work yet. It's in the `aroundprocess` function.

```
if (isset($jsLayoutResult['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']['payment']['children']['payments-list'])) {
            $componentBilling = $jsLayoutResult['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']['payment']['children']['payments-list']['children'];
            foreach ($componentBilling as $keyBilling => $value) {
                if (preg_match('/-form/', $keyBilling)) {
                    unset($componentBilling[$keyBilling]['children']['form-fields']);
                }
            }
        }
```

Thanks in advance!

P.s. for anyone who is curious about how to move the billing address to the shipping step. I followed [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/189853/move-billing-address-form-to-shipping-address-page-in-magento-2-1) guide.

---

Update: I did find this option: In admin under Stores -> Configuration -> Sales -> Checkout -> Checkout Options -> Display Billing Address On .. change it to Payment Page. And then add the following code

```
    unset($jsLayoutResult['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']['payment']['children']['afterMethods']);
```

But I would prefer a prettier option where no settings have to be changed in the admin, so if anyone knows anything?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up using this code that I found as part of an answer on a different [stackexchange](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/163408/how-to-change-the-order-of-the-billing-address-fields-on-checkout-page-in-magent) question.

```
/* config: checkout/options/display_billing_address_on = payment_method */
            if (isset($jsLayoutResult['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']
                ['payment']['children']['payments-list']['children']
            )) {
                foreach ($jsLayoutResult['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']
                         ['payment']['children']['payments-list']['children'] as $key => $payment) {

                    unset($jsLayoutResult['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']
                        ['payment']['children']['payments-list']['children'][$key]);

                }
            }
```

The problem with this is that if a shop uses checkout-agreements that those will also be deleted. Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: When using this code the "place order" button is disable

Answer (score 0):

```
public function afterProcess(\Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject, array $jsLayout) 
{
    $billingConfiguration = &$jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']
    ['children']['payment']['children']['payments-list']['children'];

   //Checks if billing step available.
   if (isset($billingConfiguration)) {
      //Iterate over billing forms.
      foreach($billingConfiguration as $key => &$billingForm) {
          //Exclude not billing forms
          if (!strpos($key, '-form')) {
              continue;
          }

            /* $billingForm['children']['form-fields']['children']['company']['visible'] = 0;

            $billingForm['children']['form-fields']['children']['city']['visible'] = 0;
            $billingForm['children']['form-fields']['children']['city']['validation']['required-entry'] = 0;

            $billingForm['children']['form-fields']['children']['region']['visible'] = 0;
            $billingForm['children']['form-fields']['children']['region_id']['visible'] = 0;

            $billingForm['children']['form-fields']['children']['telephone']['visible'] = 0;
            $billingForm['children']['form-fields']['children']['telephone']['value']   = '0000000000';
            $billingForm['children']['form-fields']['children']['telephone']['validation']['required-entry'] = 0;

            $billingForm['children']['form-fields']['children']['country_id']['visible'] = 0;
            $billingForm['children']['form-fields']['children']['country_id']['validation']['required-entry'] = 0; */

            unset($billingForm['children']['form-fields']['children']['company']);
            unset($billingForm['children']['form-fields']['children']['city']);
            unset($billingForm['children']['form-fields']['children']['region']);
            unset($billingForm['children']['form-fields']['children']['region_id']);
            unset($billingForm['children']['form-fields']['children']['telephone']);
            unset($billingForm['children']['form-fields']['children']['street']);
            unset($billingForm['children']['form-fields']['children']['country_id']);

            //unset($billingForm['children']['form-fields']['children']['postcode']);
            //print_r($billingForm['children']['form-fields']); die;
        }
    }

    return $jsLayout;
}
```